# Best way to send or pull data on first login using Firebase

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm planning to make a free-to-use app. Users can use the app without logging in, but then when they want to save their progress they can just log in and the data should automatically sync.
I don't know why, even after reading a lot of docs I'm having a hard time figuring out how to implement this the easy way.
Just to make sure I make myself clear, here's the logic I want to implement:

1. The user uses the app for the first time
2. When the user logs in
   a. If it's a first-time login, send so-far-saved local data to remote Firestore
   b. If it's not a first-time login, pull data from Firestore normally.

If I remember correctly there is a function that is triggered on the first login but I also understand functions can't directly communicate with the front so I don't see how this would help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

> Users can use the app without logging in, but then when they want to save their progress they can just log in and the data should automatically sync.

There are two ways in which you can solve this problem. The first one would be to save all the progress locally, on the user's device. Since you didn't tag any platform I will indicate to you the libraries for Android. For simple objects, you can use [SharedPereferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), for more complex objects [DataStore](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore), and for even more complex objects you can use [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room). I'm pretty sure that there are corresponding libraries for the other platforms.

The second option that you have is to [anonymously authenticate your users in Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth). This means that you can save the progress, either in [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) or in the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) under the UID that is generated by Firebase Authentication. So you'll don't have to deal with the local storage. Besides that, for all platforms, web, Android, or iOS, there is an offline persistence mechanism present. If you want to transform the anonymous account later into a real account, then you should link the anonymous account with one of the [available providers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking).

> If I remember correctly there is a function that is triggered on the first log.

Yes, that is correct, there is a function called [isNewUser()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/auth/AdditionalUserInfo#isNewUser()) which:

> Returns whether the user is new or existing